# eq-height css or JS with inner div/classes?

Tags: html, css, performance

I'm trying to create a method eq-height on this example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opXmMG

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div> class="box">
      <div class="box-head">
         <h2>Title</h2>
       </div>
      <div> class="box-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div> class="box">
      <div> class="box-head">
         <h2>Title</h2>
       </div>
      <div> class="box-body">
       <p>Second row</p>
       <p>Second row</p>
       <br>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I would like to know which is following the best up to date practices, and which should be the most performant.

And of course, putting it working. Because right now I'm not beeing able to do it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: For sure not the most performant, but here is one jQuery solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyLJPG All .box divs have same height  Btw, here are your (better) options: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Best up to date practice means can we assume that you are supporting only latest browsers. Then you can try using CSS Flexbox property and achieve it easily.

If not you have to use the tables and divs(with dispaly:table property) assuming you have fixed rows and columns for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

try my solution, I have implemented a general method to do what is neededo

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QabRQP?editors=1010

```
$( function(){
 var HightGruplist = [];
  $('*').each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).attr("HightGrup")!=null){
      var TempGrup=$(this).attr("HightGrup");
      console.log(TempGrup);
      var Found=false;
      HightGruplist.forEach(function(item,index){if (item==TempGrup){
        Found=true;
      }});
      if (!Found){
        HightGruplist.push(TempGrup);
      }
    }
  });
  HightGruplist.forEach(function(item,index){
    console.log($('*[HightGrup='+item+']'));
    $('*[HightGrup='+item+']').on('resize',function() {
      var MaxHeght=0;
      $('*[HightGrup='+item+']').each(function( index ) {
        if ($(this).height()>MaxHeght) MaxHeght = $(this).height();
      });
      console.log(MaxHeght);
      $('*[HightGrup='+item+']').height(MaxHeght);
    });
  });
});
$(function() {$('*[HightGrup]').resize();});
```

you just have to define the object groups with

```
 HightGrup="mygrup1"
```

es

```
 <div class="box-header accent" HightGrup="mygrup1">
```